# ASP.NET: Select a location on Google maps, then get the latitude and longitude to store them in the Database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-geocoding-api

In our BackOffice, we must add google map and allow user to select an specific location, then add location icon.

After user select location and its icon, we must get the selected position and save it in the database to be appeared in the our front end project.

Note that we can get it client or server side.

Comment: There are thousand different ways to do this. What is your exact problem here? Which approach have you tried and where did you face a problem? Your question does not state any of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can add google map following this [Adding a Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)

and then in you javascript use this event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {

    //lat and lng is available in e object
    var latLng = e.latLng;

});
```